# Cómo obtener el atributo itemprop con Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Acudo a los expertos porque no soy capaz de obtener el valor del atributo `itemprop=price`. Ya no sé qué más hacer. He leído la documentación pero tampoco soy capaz de resolverlo. Utilizo la clase `Simple_html_dom`.

```
<div class="prices text-left-adjust" itemprop="offers" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <div class="price taxable-price ">
        <span>
            <span itemprop="price">187.50</span>
            <meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition">
            <meta itemprop="availability" content="http://schema.org/InStock">
            <span class="euro">€
                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="price-label">
            <span class="price-label was-price linedthrough">
                250.00<span class="euro">€</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="price retail-price">
        <span>
            495.00<span class="euro">€</span>
        </span>
        <span class="price-label">PVP Italiano</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Aquí muestro el código (en pruebas). El bloque de código anterior se encuentra dentro del div `class=catalog-product`:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html("https://www.somesite.com/es/catalog/");
    $divs = $html->find('div[class=catalog-product]');
?>
<table class="bordered border-dark" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Marca</th>
        <th colspan="2">Nombre</th>
        <th colspan="2">SKU</th>
        <th colspan="2">Categoria</th>
        <th colspan="2">Tallas </th>
        <th colspan="2">Disponibilidad</th>
        <th colspan="2">Precio</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($divs as $div) { 
            $tables = $div->find('table[class="table sizes"]');
            foreach($tables as $table) {
    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $div->find('span[class="product-brand"]', 0)->plaintext; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $div->find('span[class="product-name"]', 0)->plaintext; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $div->find('span[class="product-sku"]', 0)->plaintext; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $div->find('span[class="product-category"]', 0)->plaintext; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ucwords($table->find('td', 0)->plaintext); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $table->find('td', 1)->plaintext; ?>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $div->find('span[itemprop="price"]', 0)->plaintext; ?>
                    </td>           
                </tr>       
                </tr>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Aquí muestro la imagen de la tabla que se crea con el resultado en la columna precio: Se evidencia que no está obteniendo ningún resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que estás intentando? ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Por qué usas PHP para esto y no Javascript?

Comment: Intento recolectar datos de una web y crear una tabla con esos datos. Ya he logrado obtener varios datos pero el precio no logro obtenerlo. No obtengo ningún error, solo se queda en blanco. Se me hace más difícil Javascript que PHP

Comment: Ya, si es de otra web no podrás usar Javascript, pero como no decías eso en la pregunta ese aspecto **importante** no quedaba claro. De todos modos, comparte tu código PHP, y dinos si has depurado los datos, por ejemplo, un `var_dump` de lo que obtienes con Simple_html_dom. Puedes [edit] la pregunta para agregar toda esa información, sin la cual es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Esta línea de código está bien `$div->find('span[itemprop="price"]', 0)->plaintext;` Pero eso es tomando en cuenta el `HTML` que has posteado que parece que no es el real porque no tiene elementos `table[class="table sizes"]`. Todo parece indicar que muchos –o ninguno– de los `divs` tiene el elemento `span` con parámetro `itemprop`. Verifica que todo esté bien.

Comment: Después de mucho leer y probar todo tipo de códigos lo dejo. No soy capaz de resolver este tema. Me da la impresión de que de alguna manera ese dato que intento obtener está protegido. Es curioso que cuando hago un ´echo´ sobre la variable $html`, no aparece en el código fuente el <span[itemprop=price]> del que intento obtener el dato. En su  lugar aparece un enlace como este [Precio]. Alguna idea?.